# Yellowing basil plant

Tags: basil

[image]

Are the leaves of this plant still ok to consume?

Answer (score 1):

The leaves can be naturally curly.  Often they are curly because they have been damaged.  It depends on how you are going to consume them.  I can see some holes and even a bug, so there is some infestation.

I would look at each leaf individually, and discard any with eggs or webs.  I like putting it in my normal English Breakfast Tea.  I ended up talking off new shoots before they are attacked by the bugs and putting them in a glass of water inside.  Then I can pick the leaves for a few days.

Otherwise see if you can get some "bug and insect netting" like this to cover it (after you have removed/destroyed the bugs).

[image]

I am happy spraying it with normal fly spray, covering it and waiting a few weeks before consuming it.